# unable to connect server in dot net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am developing an application to read the files from FTP server and display the file details on the windows form. Though it is working perfectly fine in my system but it throws exception when i am executing in my client's machine. Please suggest how to fix the issue. If anyone wants will provide the full source code through mail.

```
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim request As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(ftppath)

    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 10
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(user, pass)

    request.UseBinary = False
    request.UsePassive = True
    request.KeepAlive = False
    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 10
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 10
    Dim response As FtpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 10
    Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 30
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(responseStream)
    Dim lol As String

    Do
        lol = reader.ReadLine
        If Len(lol) < 1 Then Exit Do
        arr = Split(lol, vbNewLine)
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
            If Len(arr(i)) > 0 Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(arr(i))
                TextBox1.Text = arr(i)  'just testing it on a textbox
            End If
        Next
    Loop
    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 30
    MessageBox.Show("Directory List Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription)

    reader.Close()
    response.Close()
```

It throws exception

```
 ************* Exception Text **************
    System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.CheckError()
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at Sparky.Form2.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: have you tried to ftp via command line on customer machine ?

Comment: yes it is able to connect the ftp server

Comment: the exception those not show where it throws can you provide full code ?

Comment: Could it be that a firewall program is blocking your executable from accessing the Internet?

Comment: @hpfs Could you please share your mail id

Comment: did you create a user and password for ftp site on the server? or in other words are this credentials are the same for all users: `request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(user, pass)` ?

Comment: @jonathana yes the correct password is given

Comment: Ftp port (21) is open for all network subnet ip's of all the users?

Comment: @lucero i dont think its a firewall issue. Still you can give a try on my issue,email id pls.

Comment: try telnet via port 21 from one of the users computers to the ftp server ip, if you cant reach there its probably a fw issue.

Comment: @jonathana how to check it could you please help me ? (tried in cmd threw an error saying telnet is not a recognized internal or external command)

Comment: if you dont have telnet take a look at that: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/910.windows-7-enabling-telnet-client.aspx after telnet will be available write this command on the console: `telnet x.x.x.x 21` (x.x.x.x is the server ip)

Comment: @ user3928562 also compare the result against telneting from your computer (you said your pc has access) and then you will know for sure its the FW (or routing issues)

Comment: @jonathana in my system port 21 is closed(app works) but in my client's machine its open(app doesnot work).

Comment: ftp works also via port 20

Comment: @jonathana could you please take my code and drill down. i am curious to know what could be the issue

Comment: Its very late here i can take a look in it tomorrow. but it looks like an environment issue if it works on your pc

Comment: ping me your mail id please @jonathana

Comment: Ports 20, 21, and some range of ports designated by the remote FTP service above 1024 may need opened, and the windows firewall may not have granted the application the use of the internet in the clients environment. That could be group policy, user isn't an admin, etc.

Comment: @MrGadget how my client can access those ports ? is there any alternative ways to fix this considering client is never an admin?

Comment: Hi i've recv your code, it looks all fine. Infact it works smooth on my pc. Please check customer computer for firewall either the local firewall or network firewall, that maybe blocks connection.

Comment: you need to speak with the IT department, and ask them that question, go to you clients computer and enter the command `ipconfig` (via cmd) check (against the IT department) if those ip addresses have access.